# Mi programa no genera el ejecutable .exe

Tags: c#, exe

estoy haciendo una aplicación en consola pero al momento de compilar el proyecto C# no genera el ejecutable, en cambio solo genera un dll junto con otros 4 archivos que están en la carpeta de release

Alguien sabe que hice mal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Propiedades del proyecto]

[image: Archivos en carpeta release]

Comment: Nos muestras por favor lo que hay en la carpeta release?

Comment: Si el ensamblado que genera su proyecto es una dll, es porque el tipo de proyecto no es de aplicacion. DEbe configurar el tipo de proyecto como aplicación de consola en las propiedades del proyecto.

Comment: ¿Puedes pasar un pantallazo del detalle de las propiedades del proyecto? Como te comenta otro de los compañeros, es posible que tu proyecto no sea una aplicación de consola, sino una librería. Un saludo.

Comment: Si se te genera un dll es muy posible que el proyecto está configurado como librería de clases, fíjate bien que hayas elegido una aplicación de consola o aplicación WinForms/WPF. También puedes agregar un proyecto de consola a tu solución existente y marcarlo como proyecto de inicio, ahí se te generaría el .exe .

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos, ya está resuelto, el problema era que el tipo de proyecto si era en consola pero para plataforma .NET Core 2.1, hice otro proyecto de consola.NET Framework y generó el .exe
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En lugar de utilizar .NET Framework que es una plataforma que ya no tendrá ninguna actualización continúa usando .NET Core (.NET 6 en lugar de .NET Core 2.1) Puedes generar un .EXE utilizando el comando  `dotnet publish -r win-x64` Mas información: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained